# Add animated transition between gradient background change in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition, gradient

I have this code below

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyUIView: View {
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.6, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect() 
    @State var gradientBackgroundArray = [Constants.gradientFirst, Constants.gradientSecond, Constants.gradientThird]
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack(){
            ZStack(){}
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 20)
                .background(gradientBackgroundArray[0].animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4)))
            Spacer()
            ZStack(){}
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 20)
                .background(gradientBackgroundArray[0].animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4)))
            Spacer()
            ZStack(){}
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 20)
                .background(gradientBackgroundArray[0].animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4)))
        }
        .padding(10)
        .onReceive(timer){ _ in
            gradientBackgroundArray.shuffle()
        }
    }
    
}

class Constants {
    public static let gradientFirst = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
    public static let gradientSecond = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.black, .yellow]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
    public static let gradientThird = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .white]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
}
```

Now I shuffle `gradientBackgroundArray` every 0.6sec and it works fine. But the issue is that I want to add animation or transition effect to the background change after shuffling the values using this line of code:

```
.background(gradientBackgroundArray[2].animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4)))
```

But there's no animation or transition effect, it just changes instantly.

Please how can I achieve this?

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question, can you please create a [mcve]

Comment: @AshleyMills I've edited my question and added minimal reproducible example

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. What does 'toggle()` do to an array? Also - it would be easier if you were to put it all in a single code block rather than 3 separate ones, so it can be easily pasted into Xcode. Don't make us do the work for you!

Comment: @AshleyMills okay... I'll do that. And `toggle()` is a typo, it should be `shuffle()`

Comment: @AshleyMills... I've edited my question showing the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI you can’t easily animate from one set of colours to another.

You can animate the `startPoint` and `endPoint`, or the `grayScale`, `saturation`, or `hueRotation`, using one these modifiers…

```
.grayscale(_ amount: Double)
.hueRotation(_ angle: Angle)
.saturation(_ amount: Double)
```

If you want to animate the colours themselves, you'll need to create an `AnimatableModifier`, a full implementation of which can be found [here](https://www.appcoda.com/animate-gradient-swiftui/).

Comment: Thank Man... I went for the `AnimatableModifier` and it worked :)